# Providing timestamp in reference table (many to many relationship)

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, many-to-many, entity-relationship

Consider following table (reference table between tables A and B, many to many relationship):

```
A_ID int (FK),
B_ID int (FK),
change_date timestamp - represents timestamp when this relation has been created.
```

What is the best solution to provide this timestamp? When I perform insert (actually Hibernate performs), Hibernate knows only about A_ID and B_ID.

The only solution that sounds reasonable at the moment is trigger. What do you think?

Comment: You are going to have to explain your question in a bit more detail - it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: What is the problem with setting the timestamp during the insert when the relationship is created?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if it's easy then please post your solution to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to add data to a many-to-many relationship table, just map this table as an entity, and manage it as an entity.

in `A` and `B`, the mapping goes from a `@ManyToMany` to a `@OneToMany`

in the new entity say `AB`, you map `A` and `B` with `@ManyToOne` and `@Id` (both fields).

Have a look at the [Example 134](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional-with-link-entity-example) (Bidirectional many-to-many with link entity) in the hibernate reference documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DEFAULT value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMp. I think this should work.

```
A_ID int (FK),
B_ID int (FK),
change_date timestamp default Current_timestamp ON INSERT
```